Turtles don't appear when using the tracer method
Here's my code:
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

window = Screen()
window.setup(width = 800, height = 800)
window.bgcolor("Black")

position = [(-40,0), (-20,0), (0,0)]
turtles = []
window.tracer(0)
for i in range(3):
    new_turtle = Turtle("square")
    new_turtle.color("white")
    new_turtle.penup()
    new_turtle.goto(position[i])
    turtles.append(new_turtle)
    window.update()

window.update()

game_on = True
while game_on:
    for i in turtles:
        i.forward(80)
        window.update()

window.exitonclick()

It displays a black screen without visible turtles or action.
I tried adding more update() calls but no luck. How can I make sure the turtles are visible?

This question is similar to: Turtle animation is so fast in python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Remove i.forward(80) and you'll see the turtles. They're blasting off the screen because the following code says "slam the CPU as hard as possible forever":
game_on = True
while game_on:
    for i in turtles:
        i.forward(80)
        window.update()

# window.exitonclick()  # unreachable

If you used print(i.pos()) in your loop you'd see how fast the numbers become insanely large.
Never use this pattern. Use ontimer with a sensible framerate:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

window = Screen()
window.setup(width=800, height=800)
window.bgcolor("Black")

positions = [(-40, 0), (-20, 0), (0, 0)]
turtles = []
window.tracer(0)

for position in positions:
    t = Turtle("square")
    turtles.append(t)
    t.color("white")
    t.penup()
    t.goto(position)


def update():
    for t in turtles:
        t.forward(1)

    window.update()
    window.ontimer(update, 1000 // 30)


window.ontimer(update)
window.exitonclick()

